# Bonding TUN interfaces

Tags: networking, vpn, tunnel, network-bonding

I am trying to do VPN tunnels bonding as explained by [Simon Mott - VPN bonding](http://simonmott.co.uk/vpn-bonding). But after doing the steps, and when I tried to start the bonding I got the same error message as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357365/bonding-two-tun-device-connected-to-openvpn .

Is there any solution for bonding TUN interfaces?

My other options:
Is there alternative to bonding?
Can I assign MAC address to TUN interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After research I found the following:

There is **no** way to bond tun devices. TUN devices are layer 3; while bonding works on layer 2.

And **no** you can't assign MAC address to TUN devices.

The solution to bond openvpn virtual interfaces is to use [openvpn TAP](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/76-ethernet-bridging.html) instead on TUN. It has higher network overheads (bigger header and will send many broadcasting over the TAP) but it works fine with bonding.

Comment: ifenslave used to be able to work with tun devices − it does not anymore for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

This is easily doable, however don't follow [Simon Mott - VPN bonding](http://simonmott.co.uk/vpn-bonding) completely as `ifenslave` is deprecated and only works properly for bonding TUN connections on some kernels.

This is reliable:

```sh
echo "+tun0" > /sys/class/net/bond0/bonding/slaves
echo "+tun1" > /sys/class/net/bond0/bonding/slaves
```

Where `tun1` and `tun0` are the interface names of your SSH tunnels.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not answer the question − we're using OpenVPN tun devices here, not SSH tun devices.

Comment: And if SSH is creating tun devices, they won't work with ifenslave either since they are tun devices. The problem is that they are _tun_ devices.